# see who entered profile with facebook api

Tags: facebook

I have recently see facebook api, I am interested in that.

Does Facebook have any API that help me to visit who entered my profile.
I want to know is there any way to track who entered my Facebook page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To build an app that tracks profiles is against the Facebook platform policies. You can read about it in the "[Prohibited Functionality](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/policy/examples_and_explanations/Prohibited_Functionality/)" section of their policy guide.

Comment: What about this app https://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=179366935584500 . Is it a fake?

Answer (score 1):

No, Facebook does not give that information out. That would be a huge violation of privacy.